# Permissions of Current Directory

Tags: c, linux, shell, stat

I am making a program which is executed in the linux shell, which either accepts an argument (a file) and displays it's inode number, permissions, file size etc, OR if no argument is given, should read the permissions, inode number, size etc of the Directory.

I'm using stat to find out these things for files, though I am unsure how to check this information on the current directory.

here is my code:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <time.h>

void inodeNumber(struct stat info)
{

  //printf("I-node number: %ld\n", (long)info.st_ino);
  printf("%ld ", (long) info.st_ino);

}

void filePermissions(struct stat info)
{

  //printf("File Permissions: ");
  printf((S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");
  printf((info.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
  printf((info.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
  printf((info.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
  printf((info.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
  printf((info.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
  printf((info.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
  printf((info.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
  printf((info.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
  printf((info.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
  //printf("\n");
  printf(" ");

}

void numberOfLinks(struct stat info)
{

  //printf("Link number: %ld\n", (long)info.st_nlink);
  printf("%ld ", (long) info.st_nlink);
  //printf(info.st_nlink);

}

void fileSize(struct stat info)
{

  //printf("File Size: %ld\n", (long)info.st_size);
  printf("%ld ", (long) info.st_size);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  struct stat info;
  char cwd[256];

  if (argc == 1)
  {

    //current directory
    printf("No Arguments\n");

    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL )
    {

      perror("getcwd() error");
    }
    else
    {
      //find current directory
      printf("current working dir is: %s\n", cwd);

    }
    //move up directory 1 place, then test the file we were just in
    //  chdir("..");

  }

  if (stat(argv[1], &info) == -1)
  {
    perror("stat");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (argc == 2)
  {

    inodeNumber(info);
    filePermissions(info);
    numberOfLinks(info);
    fileSize(info);
    //printf("File Name Is: %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("%s", argv[1]);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried defaulting to a file name of `"."`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fstat()` works the same on files and directories. For the current directory simply use `"."`.

Comment: do you mean just call my functions like: inodeNumber(.);

Comment: No, pass "." to `stat`, to generate your `info`.

Comment: Either run your program with "." as an argument (making `argv[1]` become  "."), or add a special case for it (possibly when `argc == `1).

Comment: Great idea! Worked perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Great.. don't forget to check the green box for an answer!